# sequelize router doesn't work. when i access page, i get "Cannot GET /"

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
`var fs = require('fs');

var connect = require('connect');

var mysql = require('mysql');

var ejs = require('ejs');

const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

var router = express.Router();

const app = express();

var logger = require('morgan');`

const { sequelize } = require('./models');

//const { Router } = require('express');


sequelize.sync({ force: false })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('데이터베이스 연결 성공');
  })



.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });



app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(logger('dev'));

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));




 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('Lists');
});





app.listen(52273, function() {
    console.log('server running at http://127.0.0.1:52273');
}); 



 module.exports = router;
```

> This is my whole code that is not annotated. Please help me...
> when i access page, i get "Cannot GET /"
> i wanna show ejs file or html file.
>
> i've checked url but it is correct.
>
> and i get "GET / 404" in my terminal...  i don't know what i have to do...
> I've got no clue at all... I'm so new to this language..
> Please help me..

Comment: Please could you post the whole code? The question is unclear.

Comment: @PrathameshMore Thanks! i think i can figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `router.get` ("this code below"):

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('Lists');
});
```

with `app.get`.

Or you add `app.use(router)` below that's route.

And it will working fine.

Comment: Oh my god I think it's gonna work! Currently i have a small problem with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' " but i think i can figure it out.. maybe. Anyway I'm really thankful for your help!! 